# How to update the column values and it's corresponding index based on a values of the column?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, for-loop, dataframe

In the pandas Dataframe of following structure:

```
mcve_data =

alfa   alfa_id     beta    beta_id
a,c    7           c,de    8
c,d    7           d,f     9
l,mnk  8           c,d     9
j,k    8           d,e     9
tk,l   8           n,k     11
```

- I want to run a for-loop in each line reading the values from `key` (alfa and beta) and `key_index` (alfa_index, beta_index).
- If the values in the `key` is more than `3` in length or if any values are more than 1 character long. I want both the `key-values` and `key-index` to convert to period `.`.

**Final expected output**:

```
alfa   alfa_id     beta    beta_id
a,c    7           .      .
c,d    7           d,f     9
.      .           c,d     9
j,k    8           d,e     9
.      .           n,k     11
```

I wanted to write a function something like (but it hasn't worked properly):

```
def check_and_convert(mcve_data):
    labels = (l, l + id) for l in mcve_data.columns.values

    def convert(lines):
        for l,id in labels:
            if len(l) > 3:
                l = '.'
                id = '.'
        return l, id

        write this back to the file.
```

Any suggestions,

Answer (score 2):

You could also skip the inner for loop by using the `str` accessor to check the length of every value in a column at once:

```
keys = [k for k in df.columns if not k.endswith('_id')]
for k in keys:
    df.loc[df[k].str.len()>3,[k,k+'_id']] = '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use for loop and iterrows(). see below.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """alfa   alfa_id     beta    beta_id
a,c    7           c,de    8
c,d    7           d,f     9
l,mnk  8           c,d     9
j,k    8           d,e     9
tk,l   8          n,k     11
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace = True,  dtype ={'alfa': str, 'alfa_id': str,
                                                                 'beta': str, 'beta_id': str})

# I create a lsit of keys and key index based on '_id' distinction

keys = [i for i in df.columns if 'id' not in i]
key_ids = [i+'_id' for i in keys]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for k,kid in zip(keys, key_ids):
        if (len(row[k].split(','))>3 or any([len(i) > 1 for i in row[k].split(',')])):
            df.set_value(index, kid, '.')
            df.set_value(index, k, '.')


print df
```

results in

```
  alfa alfa_id beta beta_id
0  a,c       7    .       .
1  c,d       7  d,f       9
2    .       .  c,d       9
3  j,k       8  d,e       9
4    .       .  n,k      11
```

Comment: Thanks much for the answer. But, I want to apply for-loop, reason being - there are lots (about 100s) of `keys and key_id`, not just 2.

Comment: I edited to the code with second for loop. for all the keys and key_ids

Comment: Thanks for the update. What is the reason for the those `int` values got converted to `strings` like `'11'`. I will try to find the solution for it, but if you can do it without much hassle I would appreciate it.

Comment: pandas read_table was reading the data as int so i changed the text data to strings. but now it should be fine.